# Ruby Subtracting of Times, Timezones, Dates, or DateTimes appears broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
a.time_at
 => Mon, 12 Jul 2021 13:40:35 UTC +00:00 
b.time_at
 => Mon, 12 Jul 2021 13:52:22 UTC +00:00 

b - a
 => 707.0
```

However it should be 11 minutes ( and some seconds )

```
a.time_at.class
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone 
b.time_at.class
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone 

DateTime.parse(b.time_at.to_s) - DateTime.parse(a.time_at.to_s)
 => (707/86400)
```

Any idea why this may be?

Comment: Ruby time difference always return result in seconds. 707 seconds is true here it means that 11 minutes and 47 seconds. If you want to get minutes you should better use modulo here
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-i-2D:~:text=time%20%2D%20other_time%20%E2%86%92%20float,from%20time.

Comment: Try `ActiveSupport::Duration.build(b - a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting `Time` class objects in ruby returns a difference in seconds. `707 / 60 = 11.73`, which is 11 minutes and 46.8 seconds. You can also read about this in [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-i-2D).